# Agregar CSS a mi página web

Tags: php, wordpress

Mi problema es que al momento de cargar los CSS en la página `functions.php` que pide Wordpress, no carga ninguno de los archivos, realmente me estoy guiando desde la documentación, pero no sé si hay algo que no esta explicado de forma explicita que haya que hacer para poder cargar de forma correcta los estilos, adjunto el código:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. En este caso es más útil que cambies la imagen por el texto del código. Puedes hacerlo [editando la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/204781/edit). Gracias.

Comment: Es necesario que compruebes lo siguiente: 1. cuál es la ruta exacta que devuelve `get_template_directory_uri()`, eso puedes hacerlo poniendo la función **temporalmente** en cualquier lugar de prueba, cualquier página o en `functions.php`; 2. buscar en ese directorio exacto el directorio `css`; 3. verificar en ese directorio que existen los archivos que quieres incluir: `bootstrap.min.css` y `header.css`. Todo parece indicar que tienes los archivos en un directorio que no es.

Answer (score 3):

Puedes probar poniéndolo así:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
```

Sin los parámetros $depends, $version y $media.

Por cierto, ya pusiste, dentro del thema, las funciones `wp_head()` y `wp_footer()` en los archivos `header.php` y `footer.php` respectivamente? Eso también impidiría que funcionara